# Write a user supplied command to file

Tags: bash, heredoc, variable-expansion

I need to write a user supplied command to a file with bash.

Testcase would be `script.sh -- echo "Hello \$USER"` and I want a file containing `echo "Hello $USER"` (or `echo Hello\ $USER`) which can be executed

I'm using heredoc to write to the file, so something like

```
cat > "${FILE}" <<EOF
Your command is:
${CMD}
"$@"
EOF
```

I tried using `printf -v CMD '%q ' "$@"` but that leads to `echo Hello\ \$USER` which is not what I want.

How do I do this?

Comment: is there any reason you are using `%q`  format ? because i just tried with the `%s` and it worked

Comment: You could use `$*` like so `printf "Your command is $*\n"`

Comment: The problem is quotes/spaces: Using `$*` or `%s` will lead to `echo Hello $USER` -> 2 arguments instead of 1. This is a problem for e.g. `cat "foo with bar"` -> `cat foo with bar`

Comment: You want the space to be quoted but not the dollar sign? If so you're going to have to do some manual string manipulation; there's no escaping mechanism that's going to clairvoyantly know to quote one but not the other.

Comment: The problem starts with what's being fed to the script. Can you just have the user quote the entire string? `script.sh -- 'echo "Hello $USER"'` would be a piece of cake to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion to do it manually I came up with the following using this reasoning:

- `"$@"` syntax means: Expand all args to `"$1" "$2" ...`
- This seems not to work in my case, so do it manually:

```
    CMD=()
    for var in "$@"; do
        CMD+=( '"'"${var}"'"' )
    done

    cat > ${FILE} <<EOF
    Your command is: 
    ${CMD[@]}
```

So basically: Create an array of quoted strings. Then print this. This works for the testcase.

**But:** It fails for plenty of other things. Example: `myScript.sh -- echo "Hello \"\$USER\""` which leaves the quotes unescaped.

So I conclude that this task is not possible or at least not feasible and would suggest to use the `printf` based solution which seems to be also how other commands handle it (example: `srun/sbatch` on SLURM)